# Python Regex Expression that finds variable string between whitespace, punctuation and/ or string end

Tags: python, regex, python-re, python-regex

I need the regex expression to find a substring (it's a variable) that is either preceded/followed by punctuation, whitespaces or the start/end of the string. I don't know the size or content of the substring. I've come up with `[\?\.!\- ]1abc[\?\.!\- ]` (this is a specific example where the substring is 1abc) but I don't know how to add start/end as a possibility. With the following list:

- "1abc"
- "2131abc2411abc"
- "Hausstrasse 1abc"
- "Parkallee 1abc "
- "1abc-2"
- "abc-def-1abc!"

I'd want the matches to be on all lines but not "2131abc2411abc". Alternatively I tried the pattern `[\?\.!\- ]*1abc[\?\.!\- ]*` but with this, "2131abc2411abc" returns matches also.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Please state the expected output for each case. Also, online tools such as https://regex101.com are good places to try out our ideas.

Comment: What is so special about "2131abc2411abc" that it should not match?

Comment: @HaiVu there is already a working response but to make it more clear for someone else who might use this: As specified, I only want my expression to trigger if my string is at the start, right after a punctuation or right after a whitespace AND it is followed either by the end of the string a punctuation or a whitespace. "2131abc2411abc" does not fit these criterias. Therefore it shouldn't match. I used regex101 and would recommend it to anyone testing around, too (I simply didn't know the necessary step)! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly use `(^|[\?\.!\- ])` to match one of the boundary characters or the start of the string. For the end, use `$`.

In addition, directly use `1abc` to match that substring literally rather than putting it into a character class which matches only one character from the set.

```py
re.search(r'(^|[\?\.!\- ])1abc([\?\.!\- ]|$)', s)
```